# Django "cannot import name PMMail"

Tags: python, django, middleware, postmark

I'm a little stuck.

I'm configuring a project in my mac to work with it (I worked on it in the past in the same computer), but had to format it.

When trying `python runserver` it works fine, but when try to load it in browser I get this:

[image]

And I get this in terminal:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.2, using settings '****.settings'
Development server is running at http:// 127 .0.0.1:8000 /
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware quizzer.views: "cannot import name PMMail"
[12/Sep/2014 11:31:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware quizzer.views: "cannot import name PMMail"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware quizzer.views: "cannot import name PMMail"
[12/Sep/2014 11:35:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware quizzer.views: "cannot import name PMMail"
```

**EDIT**

This is my middleware classes from settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'quizzer.views.FacebookMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'quizzer.middleware.SetGroupMiddleware',
'quizzer.django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.XsSharing',

# Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
# 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Please post your settings.py esp. the middleware classes.

Comment: OK, done it, but I don't know how this can help. It works, what is wrong is my pc configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have not installed the [PMMail](https://github.com/themartorana/python-postmark) lib.

To install with pip run `pip install git+https://github.com/themartorana/python-postmark.git`

Comment: I think I have it installed, but I'll try in case I'm mistaken